# what i'm i doing wrong on this algorithm?

Tags: java

I've been stuck on this code for a couple of hours.
The sum is `S = 1-x + x^2 - x^3 + x^4`.
We ask for `X` and `N` with starting value of `i = 0`.
Whenever the previous exponent (`i`) is odd we add `x^i`, and
if the previous exponent is even we subtract `x^i`.
I've put them on a loop but i can't seem to get the sum correctly.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class hw1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("Sum = 1^0-x^1+x^2-x^3..+x^n");
            System.out.println("Enter number X");
            int X = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter number N");
            int N = scan.nextInt();
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
                if (i < N) {
                    if (i % 2 != 0)    // if I is even 
                    {
                        sum = sum - (X ^ i);
                    } else    // if I is odd 
                    {
                        sum = sum + (X ^ i);
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Z is " + sum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please look at the how to ask a question page on SO ( http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ). Would be easier to (help) answer if the full question was posted. Also - why do a for loop with the condition of `i <= N` but then immediately inside theres an `if` statement contradicting that condition (`if (i < N)` ). Plus, the `^` operator in java is not for exponent, it is Bitwise exclusive OR (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html ) - instead try something like `Math.pow(...)`

Comment: Thank you so much i got it working now i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I fixed a few things in your code:

1. I switched the `^` operator (which, as @Nick Bell pointed out, is a bitwise exclusive OR) for [`Math.pow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-).
2. I fixed the spelling of your variables `x` and `n`. In Java, convention is to give variables names that start with lower-case. Upper-cases (`X` and `N`) are reserved for constants (fields marked `final`) and for classes (as opposed to objects). Note that this is only a convention, and that the code works fine both ways. It just helps in reading the code.
3. Your odd/even check was inverted: `x % 2 == 0` is `true` for even numbers.
4. The reason that you inverted your odd/even check was probably the two operations on `sum` were inverted. Compare with the description of your problem in the first paragraph of your question, you'll see where you went wrong.
5. The `if i < N` check was redundant. It you really wanted to limit computation to `i < N`, you should specify it directly in your first  for loop.
6. I added two try/catch blocks with infinite loops that break when an integer is entered, because your previous code threw an exception and stopped if you entered something else than a well-formed integer (such as letters, or a decimal value). Up to you to keep them or delete them.
7. By the way, initializing `x` and `n` to `0` is now redundant, since your code is guaranteed to assign them another value right away.

This is the updated code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Sum = 1^0-x^1+x^2-x^3..+x^n");
        System.out.println("Enter number X");
        int x = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                x = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Enter an integer.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Enter number N");
        int n = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                n = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
                break;
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                System.out.println("Enter an integer.");
            }
        }
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0)    // if I is even
                sum = sum + Math.pow(x, i);
            else    // if I is odd
                sum = sum - Math.pow(x, i);
        }
        System.out.println("Z is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: `import java.util.Scanner;
public class hw1 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
  double i,x=0,n=0,sum=0;
  try (Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in))
  {
  System.out.println("Enter X"); 
  int X=scan.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter N"); 
  int N=scan.nextInt();
   for ( i=0; i<=N; i++)
   {
    if (i%2 !=0)     
    {
    sum= sum - Math.pow(X,i);
    }
    else   // if I is odd 
    {
    sum= sum + Math.pow(X,i);
    }
   }
  System.out.println("Z is " + sum);
  }
 }
}
`